# Does the individual sampler advanced value settings overrides the http request defaults advanced settings?

Tags: jmeter, httprequest

I have one HTTP Request default that have optimized basic and advanced settings for the individual requests samplers to adapt.

[image]

And I now have updated one individual sampler advanced settings Connection timeout.

[image]

This I think is a basic question, does the individual sampler overrides the HTTP Requests defaults? or is it the other way around (Requests defaults overrides the individual sampler)?
If the former, does it apply to all the inputs or just the one I have updated Connection timeout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[HTTP Request Defaults](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/why-its-so-important-use-jmeters-http-request-defaults/) provides **default** values for all the [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers in the HTTP Request Defaults [scope](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#scoping_rules)

When you amend a value in the single HTTP Request sampler the default value becomes **overridden** for particular this sampler, other samplers will have the values you specify in the HTTP Request Defaults.

Changes are not propagated from the individual Samplers to the defaults, the direction is only from Defaults to Samplers.