# JMeter Embedded resource in HTTP request defaults vs individual sampler

Tags: jmeter

Currently I have a test plan that has:

1. "Embedded resource from HTML files" and parallel download set at the HTTP request defaults level of the thread group
2. HTTP samplers under a few transaction controllers with the setting set to the individual sampler level
3. HTTP samplers under other Tx controllers without the setting set at their individual sampler levels.

My question:
Does the HTTP request defaults property about embedded resources propagate to the samplers at #3?

My understanding from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60813632/does-the-individual-sampler-advanced-value-settings-overrides-the-http-request-d): Yes it will reflect which means all the samplers in my test plan will have the embedded resources downloaded using parallel threads

Is this right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is right, HTTP Request Defaults proparages **default** changes to all samplers in its [scope](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#scoping_rules)

1. The "defaults" will be applied to **both** `HTTP Request` 1 and `HTTP Request 2`

   [image]
2. Here the "defaults" will be applied to both `HTTP Request 1` and `HTTP Request 2`, **but not** to the `HTTP Request 3`

   [image]
3. And here the "defaults" will be applied to the `HTTP Request 3` **only**

   [image]

More information: [JMeter Scoping Rules - The Ultimate Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-scoping-rules-the-ultimate-guide)